# Popup message based on a query calculation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

I am using a table called "Numbers" in the table your auto ID field and Cellphonenumber. I have create a form where the user can input the cell phone number only. Once they press Enter it runs the query called NumberCount where it take the cell phone being entered and the query counts how many times it has been entered and gives you the value in a field called TimesBrought which is a calculated field based on number of entries of that cell phone number entered. Now what i want to do is have a pop up message that will pop up if the cellphone number has been entered 10 or 20 or 30 or 40 times. I have tried using a IIf statment under the query criteria. But i'm not coming right. Please can someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: A MsgBox cannot be programmed in a query.

Comment: Use code in textbox BeforeUpdate event to validate data and run MsgBox. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Just to be clear on the form itself CellphoneNumber Field i go to before update under event and use and can i use an if statement there for example if Cellphonenumberfeild is equal to the the Cellphonenumber field for the query and if the Count is = to 10,20,30,40, Then message box else do nothing.

Comment: Put code in macro or VBA procedure, not directly in the event property.